# How do you safely convert an Ext JS 4 Chart to an image?

Tags: javascript, image, extjs, charts

Just wondering if anyone knows how you would obtain an image from an Ext JS Chart in a secure manner?

I noticed that the Ext JS 4.1 preview has a "save" method that allows you to get a .png image from a chart but looking at the source code it seems to just sends the definition of the svg/vml from your chart to a Sencha server which is not secure enough for what I need.

Comment: You can use ImageMagic for example and do such conversion on you server.

Comment: I don't think that supports VML but I guess it should be possible to convert VML manually to SVG server side.  However, there is a potential security risk that you are sending the actual definition of the chart over the Internet (including the data).

Comment: But you must also download data to the browser via Internet, so what's the difference? You can always use secure connection.

Comment: Good point on the secure connection!  I guess you're right - getting the data has the same risk as sending it again.  The difference is that your server will process any SVG you give it - there's no way to know if it's a request to have the chart converted to an image or just a SVG of some inappropriate content - although I guess POSTing the data would alleviate the major problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this before 4.1 so I never used the Sencha server conversion. ImageMagick didn't have a conversion for html to image but wkhtmltoimage worked great on my own server side.

The charts have to be in their own distinct page and [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) will convert it to whatever format you need.

Comment: Looks promising, I can only hope I'm allowed to install it!