# ExtJs bar chart export as png or jpeg image

Tags: extjs

I am trying to find out Export feature for Bar charts to JPEG/PNG... I didn't find this any where in extJs examples section. Please let me know if this feature is available in Extjs charts or not.
Please share the examples or URLs on this, if any.

Any thing on this will be much appreciable!!

Answer (score 0):

They have something now for 4.1 where they convert it on the sencha server for you. I haven't tried that but [here's how I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8807537/1062992).